# Install RSAT on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I want to run the Active Directory Users and Computers App on Windows 10 to administer AD without having to RDP to the domain controllers and I've installed RSAT from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45520 and installed the US Language pack as I read somewhere that was required, but it's still not showing up for me.

Any ideas on how to get it installed?

Comment: What's not showing up for you? I just installed that, and everything appears to be present.

Comment: Failover Cluster Manager and Active Directory for Users and Computers just doesn't show up. I am in the UK if that makes any difference. I looked for it `%SystemRoot%\system32\dsa.msc` but it's just not there. Neither is `Cluadmin.msc`

Comment: I installed this on my Windows 10 updated PC recently too since the Windows 7 RSAT tools that were on it already disappeared after the upgrade... but after installing this update and then rebooting, all showed up as usual again on Windows 10 just as it worked on Windows 7 for the most part that I can tell thus far. I would maybe uninstall the tools, reboot the machine, reinstall the tools, and then reboot and check again for a potentially simple solution in case it was a one-time fluke or something. Check your event viewer logs too and see if anything indicates a problem there.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT It looks like it's not installed. When I installed it takes about 3 seconds, almost like it's not doing anything and reports success.

Comment: I think it's in the **Programs and Features** as a MS Update but I cannot verify at the moment what this is on Windows 10 but it appears to be listed there as **Update for Microsoft Windows (958830)** on Windows 7 so you may want to see if it's listed as that perhaps.

Comment: On win 10 it's KB2693643 and that's not listed in my installed updates, even though I just installed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the US Language pack, rebooted and then reinstalled RSAT and it worked. See http://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/637-rsat-for-windows-10-kb2693643-doesn-t-install